# socket.recvfrom function returning a tuple (python)

Tags: python, sockets, pickle

I'm a python noobie and I must create a Truco (brazillian game, if you don't know) game that connects 4 machines. I'm doing it with classes, using pickles to transfer it to a socket. According to what I could find online, this should work, but my recv is a tuple, and I can't use loads from a tuple. I've tried to convert it to a list, and then to a string, but nothing works!

```
def recv(self, machine):
    PORT = 5054
    HOST = ''
    orig = (socket.gethostbyname(HOST), PORT)
    machine._socketrcv.bind(orig)
    recv = machine._socketrcv.recvfrom(1024)
    return pickle.loads(recv)
```

And here is my send method:

```
def sent(self, m, machine):
    PORT = 5054
    dest = (machine._host, PORT)
    self._socketsnd.sendto(m._dados,dest)
```

Where m._dados is self.dados = pickle.dumps(dados, 2)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to read through [socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) and then do something like `recv = machine._socketrcv.recvfrom(1024)[0]`

> `socket.recvfrom(bufsize[, flags])`
>
> Receive data from the socket. The return value is a pair (string, address) where string is a string representing the data received and address is the address of the socket sending the data. See the Unix manual page recv(2) for the meaning of the optional argument flags; it defaults to zero. (The format of address depends on the address family — see above.)

Answer (score 1):

`recvfrom` returns a tuple with the data and the address (more info can be found in the [socket documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html)). Unlike some other languages Python lets you put a tuple on the left hand side of an assignment, so if you do something like this:

```
data, (address, port) = machine._socketrcv.recvfrom(1024)
```

you will get access to all the information you need in separate named variables. In your case you just need the data:

```
pickle.loads(data)
```

Comment: the second element in the `recvfrom`  return is a 2 element tuple itself which contains the IP address and the port that the connection was made on. As far as I know this code works fine.